# javascript expand/collapse text - collapse on default

Tags: javascript, if-statement, expand

I'm very inexperienced in javascript but have managed (with the help of google) to put together the following expandable/collapsible link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a) {
   var e = document.getElementById(a);
   if(!e) return true;

   if(e.style.display == "none") {
      e.style.display = "block"
   }
   else {
      e.style.display = "none"
   }
   return true;
}
</script>
<p>
  <input onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" style="font-size:18px; color:#008080;" type="text" value="LINK TO EXPAND" />
</p>
<p id="para1">
   <strong><em>text text text text</em></strong>
</p>
```

The only problem with it is that it is expanded by default and I wanted it collapsed by default. Can anyone help with this? Thank you!
Also, if anyone knows how to get +/- signs next to the link that change depending on whether it is expanded or collapsed, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a) {
   var e = document.getElementById(a);
   var toggleIcon = document.getElementById('toggle-icon');
   if(!e) return true;

   if(e.style.display == "none") {
      e.style.display = "block";
      toggleIcon.innerHTML = '-';
   }
   else {
      e.style.display = "none";
      toggleIcon.innerHTML = '+';
   }
   return true;
}
</script>
<p>
  <input onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" style="font-size:18px; color:#008080;" type="text" value="LINK TO EXPAND" />
  <span id="toggle-icon">+</span>
</p>
<p id="para1" style="display: none;">
   <strong><em>text text text text</em></strong>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting in style statement the display option like below:

```
<p id="para1" style="display:none"><strong><em>text text text text</em></strong></p>
```

That can default collapse when you open your html, hope it help you...

Answer (score 0):

#### Options 1:

Add this to your css to hide it by default:

```
#para1 {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Options 2:

Move your script down, and call it initially `toggleMe('para1');` so you will hide it first.

```html
<p>
  <input onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" style="font-size:18px; color:#008080;" type="text" value="LINK TO EXPAND" />
</p>
<p id="para1">
   <strong><em>text text text text</em></strong>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a) {
   var e = document.getElementById(a);
   if(!e) return true;

   if(e.style.display == "none") {
      e.style.display = "block"
   }
   else {
      e.style.display = "none"
   }
   return true;
}
toggleMe('para1');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel has the correct answer to your question. This is a bit more than you asked for, but I think you will have a better time if you manipulate classes instead of element styles properties. Just makes it a bit more flexible.

In the example below I wrapped your code in a common element and then changed that element's class to achieve your desired effect. That let me easily add in your plus and minus too.

It's a little raw but you can see where this can take you. Hope it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/6xoe1b94/

```js
function toggleMe(a) {
   
   var e = document.getElementById('wrapper');
   if(! e.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.classList.add('active');
   }
   else {
      e.classList.remove('active');
   }
}
```

```css
#para1{
  display:none;
}
.active #para1{
  display:block;
}

#plus{
  display:inline-block;
}
#minus{
  display:none;
}
.active #plus{
  display:none;
}
.active #minus{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
<p>
  <input onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" style="font-size:18px; color:#008080;" type="text" value="LINK TO EXPAND" /><span id='plus'>+</span><span id='minus'>-</span>
</p>
<p id="para1">
   <strong><em>text text text text</em></strong>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a solution that removes the **javascript** and **css** from your **html**. I also changed your expand/collapse `element` to a div instead of input. I've added a span element within the `div` that changes it's text content (either + or -) based on whether `#para1` is `displayed` or not. Also, in css I added `display: none;` to `#para1` (this initially hides the element), `cursor: pointer;` (shows it is clickable when the user hovers over it) `user-select: none;` (stop div from highlighting when user clicks on it).

```js
// store elements
var expandEl = document.getElementById("expand");
var plusMinusEl = document.getElementById("plusMinus");
var para1El = document.getElementById("para1");

// toggle function: pass element as argument
function toggleMe(el) {
  // check if element is hidden
   if(el.offsetParent === null) {
      plusMinusEl.textContent = "-";
      el.style.display = "block"
   }
   else {
      plusMinusEl.textContent = "+";
      el.style.display = "none"
   }
}

// click function for expand div
expandEl.addEventListener("click", function() {toggleMe(para1El)});
```

```css
#expand {
  font-size:18px; 
  color:#008080;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;  /* stop div from highlighting */
}

#para1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="expand">
LINK TO EXPAND <span id="plusMinus">+</span>
</div>
<p id="para1"><strong><em>text text text text</em></strong></p>
```